# Can I reuse my Office 2010 licence key when upgrading my OS to 8?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, microsoft-office, upgrade, license

As some others have been doing, I have been procrastinating upgrading my operating system. A lot. I'm still on XP (Don't laugh, I can't see spending the money), and since MS is pulling the plug on patches after thirteen years, it's definitely time to upgrade, especially with the $40 deal.

**Here's the problem:**

I have Office 2010 installed, and I don't want to waste another key. Will it transfer my key/deactivate it?

[**[Related](https://superuser.com/questions/425850/can-i-unactivate-a-microsoft-office-2010-key-to-install-on-a-new-machine)**]
**This doesn't cover upgrading, I know I can call Microsoft, but does the upgrade tool automatically transfer/deactivate my licence?** I bought it in a three licence pack, so will I have two licences or one remaining when I install it on Windows 8? (I only have it on one computer now, but I want to use it on two more computers.)

Please request clarifications in the comments; I will clarify anything ASAP. I tried to make this as easy to read as possible, but there may be something needing to be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you keep using it on the same machine there shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: I find it best to simply disconnect from the internet when installing and use the provided phone number to activate the product. This is slightly more work, but it cuts back on the errors. It is perfectly legal to reuse it too, no worries  there.

Comment: @iamwpj So Microsoft will make sure that it's okay? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a note on your upgrade: You will need to do a fresh install going from XP to windows 8, so back up all your info (docs. .xls and so on). This will require you to reinstall Office 2010.

Secondly, Microsoft allows for a lic to be used on one computer and one mobile device. If your thinking about adding MS Office to a laptop along with a desktop than that is ok as per EULA:

> 2. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
>      a. One Copy per Device. You may install one copy of the software on one
>      device. That device is the “licensed device.”
>      b. Licensed Device. You may only use one copy of the software on the
>      licensed device at a time.
>      c. Portable Device. You may install another copy of the software on a
>      portable device for use by the single primary user of the licensed device.

The worst case senario is that you would have to call Microsoft if your lic amount goes over the lic quantity to clear it up. And they will clear it up if you explain what you have done (new os vs on old computer vs installation of Office on another new computer).

Comment: +1 For not about documents... I know that but a good reference.